# How to get the total number of issues of a JIRA Project?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

Since JIRA API only allows to make a search request with a max result of 1000 issues, I need to know if there is a way to get the total number of issues a project so I can iterate through all thousands of issues.

```
IRestResponse responseIssues = client.Execute(new RestRequest("search?jql=project=" + "\"DATPROJECT\"" + "&maxResults=5000&fields=assignee,summary,timetracking,resolutiondate,resolution,worklog", Method.GET));
```

I am currently doing like the code above but I only get 1000 results and not 5000 that I need. I know that I can use the filter "startAt" to iterate over all results but I don't know how many issues exist.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The search rest point returns total number of issues for a given JQL search. Example result from [documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/latest/#d2e417)

```
{
"expand": "names,schema",
"startAt": 0,
"maxResults": 50,
"total": 1,
"issues": [
    {
        "expand": "",
        "id": "10001",
        "self": "http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/10001",
        "key": "HSP-1"
    }
]
```

}

This `"total":1` value is the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Hey from rest Api I don't find any rest where you can get all issue.but if you want all issue you can get it from java side. if you need total number of issues use

```
long getIssueCountForProject (Long projectId)
```

and if you want all issues and want to iterate it use

```
Collection<Long> getIssueIdsForProject (Long projectId)
```

please refer atlassian [documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/javadoc/jira/4.4.1/reference/com/atlassian/jira/issue/IssueManager.html#getIssueCountForProject(java.lang.Long)) for all this method.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use maxResults=0 to get only descriptive data omitting the actual results.

For example, if we want to know the amount of open issues for the currently logged in user:

```
rest/api/2/search?jql=project=SP+AND+statusCategory!=3+AND+assignee+in+(currentUser())&maxResults=0
```

The result:

```
{
  "startAt": "0",
  "maxResults": "0",
  "total": "68",
  "issues": [
  ]
}
```

The "total" field here is just what we need.